# How to get the DAG chain execution time in Airflow?

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, airflow-scheduler

Lets say I have two DAG, where dag2 executed dag1 as part of it's flow using TriggerDagRunOperator as follows:

- dag1: task1 > task2 > task3
- dag2: task4 > dag1 > task5

Now lets say dag2 is scheduled for once a day at 5PM.
Is there a way for me to get the execution timestamp for dag2 (the parent DAG) while I'm running dag1?
Is there any built-in parameter that holds that value?

And if something happened and dag2 was triggered later than usual, lets say 6PM same day, then I still want to get the original scheduling time - that is 5PM while I'm in dag1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass a function to the `python_callable` argument of `TriggerDagRunOperator` that injects the `execution_date` into the triggered DAG:

```
def inject_execution_date(context, dag_run_obj):
  dag_run_obj.payload = {"parent_execution_date": context["execution_date"]}
  return dag_run_obj

[...]

trigger_dro = TriggerDagRunOperator(python_callable=inject_execution_date, [...])
```

You can access this in the child DAG with `context["conf"]["parent_execution_date"]`

Comment: Thanks joeb! and this executio_date is it a built-in parameter? I don't need to define it myself anywhere?

Comment: @Maayan yes, it's included by Airflow